# Форма вывода результата тестирования

Tags: java, eclipse, appium

Написал тест кейс.

Как вывести результат тестирования? Желательно в файле, чтобы в случае с негативным кейсом отправлять сразу разработчику.

Перефразирую:
Все результаты выводятся в консоль. Как сделать так, чтобы все, что вывелось в консоль, записывалось в файл?

```
try 
    {
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung a3"); 
        caps.setCapability("udid", "c2cfde26"); // ID
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android"); // платформа
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2"); // версия
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.kbl.kbl"); 
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.kbl.kbl.gui.splash.SplashActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true"); // перезагрузка приложения при запуске кода 
        System.out.println("Инициализация оборудования прошла успешно");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Инициализация оборудования что то пошло не так");
    }
    try
    {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Ошибка команда не отправилась");
    }
    try 
    {
        dynamicElement2 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("com.kbl.kbl:id/btn_add_contact")));
        System.out.println("Приложение запустилось");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Запуск не удался");
    }
    try 
    {   
        List<MobileElement> HorizontalScrollView = driver.findElements(By.id("com.kbl.kbl:id/sliding_tabs"));
        a_1++;
        MobileElement HSV = HorizontalScrollView.get(0);
        a_1++;
        List<MobileElement> Iv = HSV.findElements(By.className("android.widget.ImageView"));
        a_1++;
        Iv.get(0).click();
        System.out.println("Пепеход на окно контакты");
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Ошибка перехода на контакты");
        if (a_1 == 1) 
        {
            System.out.println("Ошибка на уровне :" + a_1);
        }
        if (a_1 == 2) 
        {
            System.out.println("Ошибка на уровне :" + a_1);
        }
        if(a_1 == 3) 
        {
            System.out.println("Ошибка на уровне :" + a_1);
        }
        System.out.println("Приложение будет закрыто");
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: Написал тесткейс - приложи его к вопросу: будет понятнее что вы хотите сделать. Но вообще, результаты тестов не посылаются по почте и не сохраняются в файл - а выводятся в CI/CD систему.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос